# Why is it that Draco and Harry don't get along?

Tags: harry-potter

I don't quite understand where the disliking came from?

Comment: Were you perhaps reading a different book than the rest of us?

Comment: I haven't read the books I'm purely asking the questions the movies don't give the answers to! Which I already know is a lot before you start preaching @Richard

Comment: Even from the movies you can see that.. I also haven't read the books.

Comment: Frankly, I think that question can/should be asked about many works of fiction in other franchises. The plot device of creating "conflict" by having characters start a life-lasting vendetta based on seemingly insignificant disagreements often leaves viewers to wonder how said characters can possibly get along in everyday life at all.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Draco is a hateful, arrogant, supremacist bigot. You call that "insignificant disagreement"?

Comment: @Cephalopod: I have met a number of children that I found hateful or arrogant when I went to elementary school. Unsurprisingly, I am not considering them to be my nemesis nowadays; I might even have a brief chat with them if I ever see any of them again.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Ah, but did any of them happen to murder your mentor? That might change your opinion...

Comment: @Richard: They did not, and that may serve as a good justification in this particular case.

Comment: @Richard: Draco didn't murder anyone. That was kind of his redemption. Personally, I blame the parents.

Comment: @MartinMcCallion - Draco didn't murder Dumbledore, but he was certainly instrumental in allowing it to happen.

Comment: @Richard That's true...

Comment: Do you mean **initially** as in, right from the outset? Or, throughout the entire series?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Draco and Harry had an initial disagreement which was *very* deep-seeded (Mud-bloods vs Pure Bloods)!

Comment: Also, I'm not going to close this question as it can be methodically answered (might try it later myself)... http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18501/why-was-ron-so-nasty-to-hermione/55218#55218 and http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18555/why-did-snape-have-it-in-for-neville/52228#52228

Comment: @Mooz: In real life, "very deep-seeded disagreements" between two persons mean that the respective people simply don't touch that particular topic of disagreement, or they just avoid talking to each other in general, and everyone is happy.

Comment: The reason is how friendly Harry goes with Hagrid and Ron Weasley.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's pretty obvious right from the start that Draco displays many of the same traits as Harry's cousin Dudley. In their first encounter he shows that he is selfish and spoiled. On top of that he insults Harry's newfound friend Hagrid and shows a contempt for muggles:

> ‘That’s Hagrid,’ said Harry, pleased to know something the boy didn’t. ‘He works at Hogwarts.’
> ‘Oh,’ said the boy, ‘I’ve heard of him. He’s a sort of servant, isn’t he?’
> ‘He’s the gamekeeper,’ said Harry. He was liking the boy less and less every second.
> ‘Yes, exactly. I heard he’s a sort of savage – lives in a hut in the school grounds and
> every now and then he gets drunk, tries to do magic and ends up setting fire to his bed.’

and

> ‘My father’s next door buying my books and mother’s up the street looking at wands,’ said the boy. He had a bored, drawling voice. ‘Then I’m going to drag them off to look at racing brooms. I don’t see why first-years can’t have their own. I think I’ll bully father into getting me one and I’ll smuggle it in somehow.’
>
> Harry was strongly reminded of Dudley.

When they later meet on the train he insults Harry's new friend Ron, openly displays arrogance towards other wizard families and he has two thuggish looking "bodyguards" on either side of him:

> ‘You’ll soon find out some wizarding families are much better than
> others, Potter. You don’t want to go making friends with the wrong
> sort. I can help you there.’
>
> He held out his hand to shake Harry’s, but Harry didn’t take it.
>
> ‘I think I can tell who the wrong sort are for myself, thanks,’ he
> said coolly.

Within seconds they're nose-to-nose getting ready to fight.